# Problems to install different INET version manually

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to install inet in omnet manually and I am facing some issues. I followed the INSTALL instruction, that is given in inet, but even for different omnet and inet versions I get the same errors when trying to compile inet. (I am using a Windows 10 Computer)

One of the Errors I get:

```
note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
inet/common/TLVOption.cc:103:27: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char&' from an rvalue of type 'char'
 doParsimUnpacking(b, s);
```

There are some more errors in TVLOption, but I don't think, that there is a problem in the code, because if I install inet over "Help -> Install Simulation Models..." everything works fine.

Do you have any clue, where I might have done something wrong? (I used "tar xvfz inet-version-src.tgz" to extract inet, so that shouldn't be the problem)

Thank you for the effort!

Comment: Which INET version are you using? The 3.99 development version is meant to be used for specially patched OMNeT++ 5.2 versions...

Comment: I have tested different versions of inet including the stable versions 3.4.0 and 3.5.0.

Comment: And which OMNeT++ version are you using? GCC or Clang compiler?

Comment: I have tried with Omnet 5.1 and 5.1.1 with Clang compiler. I will try GCC tomorrow.

Comment: Be careful with the version dependence. INET 3.4 is meant for OMNeT 5.0, INET 3.5 for OMNeT 5.1.
I recommend using OMNeT 5.2 and INET 3.6.2, works just fine. You do not need to unpack the INET archive by the way, just use "import existing project" and then select the archive file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing the compressed and not the exported file, it worked for me for some reason. 
I now used Omnet 5.1.1 with inet 3.5 and clang compiler.
Thank you for your help!